# Quickly show Readability Statistics in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, statistics, grammar

Is there a quick way to show the readability statistics for Microsoft Word 2013 or 2016 documents, without having to correct them first?

I know how to [enable the readability statistics](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/test-your-document-s-readability-85b4969e-e80a-4777-8dd3-f7fc3c8b3fd2) so that they show when you finish checking spelling and grammar.  However, Microsoft's instructions say:

> Important: You have to correct, or Ignore, all spelling errors found in the document before the readability statistics will display. If there are still any red squiggles in the file, the readability statistics won't display.

I want to get readability statistics of long, badly written documents that often contain many non-dictionary terms, so I don't want to have to go through correcting everything first.  Even just repeatedly hitting Ignore takes a long time.  Is there a way that I can trigger the statistics dialog to show without going through the whole spell check?  Perhaps using VBA?

I have tried marking the whole text as "Do not check spelling or grammar", but then I just see zeroes for all the statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a VBA macro to display these values without completing the spell check.

The document should be first saved as `.docm` to allow macros, then use
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to enter the VBA editor, use menu *Insert > Module*
and set the contents to the following:

```
Sub Readability()
    Dim DocStats As String
    Dim MBTitle As String
    Dim J As Integer

    MBTitle = "Readability Statistics"
    DocStats = ""
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        For J = 1 to 10
            DocStats = DocStats & .ReadabilityStatistics(J)
            DocStats = DocStats & ": "
            DocStats = DocStats & .ReadabilityStatistics(J).Value
            DocStats = DocStats & vbCrLf
        Next J
    End With
    MsgBox DocStats, vbOKOnly, MBTitle
End Sub
```

You may use <kbd>F5</kbd> in the editor to run/test the macro.
In everyday use you may run the macro from the
[Developer tab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-the-developer-tab-on-the-ribbon?view=vs-2017)
or
[Assign a macro to a ribbon button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c)
or do
[Adding a Macro to the Quick Access Toolbar](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T006011_Adding_a_Macro_to_the_Quick_Access_Toolbar.html).

Source : [Only Showing Readability Statistics](https://word.tips.net/T001784_Only_Showing_Readability_Statistics.html).